# Responsive box needs to fit the rest of the page

Tags: html, css

I sit with a little teasing at the Responsive design on my page... 
In a PC browser all is as it should ..

But on other mobile devices, the boxes not really fit ...

The site is www.ivÃ¦rksÃ¦tterpodcast.dk

here can you see the problem from an iphone 5 browser. 
http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/ # u = http://ivÃ¦rksÃ¦tterpodcast.dk

So if you click load the page from a mobile browser and brows through the menu, you'll see the page doesn't fit.

I tried to chance this:

```
page_content {
width: 824px;
opacity: 0.8;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 50px auto 120px;
padding: 5px 0 30px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

but that doesn't help.

I think its something with: media queries maybe?

Well if you some kind can install a plugin with a responsive menu which will fix my other issue, that would be fine aswell.
Hope you can help ...

Comment: You can read about twitter-bootstrap 3 - http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/. It is responsive design, which has a lot of useful things for UI.

Comment: take a look at bootstrap style sheet you can get all the media queries from it. :)

Comment: ok I will take a look at it

Comment: Your link is broken... I can't see the problem.
You can also take a look at ZURB Foundation 5 as an alternative to Bootstrap: http://foundation.zurb.com/

Answer (score 0):

How would something like this do for you.  You can expand the window to see it is responsive.

```
.wrap {
    max-width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.page-content {
    width: 92%;
    float:left;
    opacity: 0.8;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:10px 2%;
    padding:20px 2%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

[Check it out on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asapmmeehan/372Dg/1/)